# OPENROWSET with custom delimiter

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I have a text file generated using SSIS. it has column delimiter "|@;@|" and the rowdelimiter is "\r\n|\r\n". 
how can i execute "OpenRowSet" query to get specific columns out of this text file?

below is the query i am trying to execute

```
SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\temp\filename.txt',FORMATFILE = 'C:\temp\filename.fmt') AS a;
```

and the format file first three columns are as below. due to character constraint not able to post all columns data here

> 

```
12.0
32
1       SQLCHAR             0       21      "|@;@|"      1     DimSiteID                                                            ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       21      "|@;@|"      2     DimActivityID                                                        ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       128     "|@;@|"      3     ActivityCategoryCode                                                 Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC
```

i am getting error as below:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Please help to identify the error in my query

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason for this issue could be mismatch with no of column in  csv file and table column .  in example also first row have 1 column and third row have 2 column...

Comment: The Problem is that my source data file(Text File) is unicode. do i need to add anything in openrowset query to let it work with unicode text file?

Comment: open in note++ (with show all character mode ) and check if you columndelimiter are proper